# starting react native app

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm starting work on React Native, using create-reactive-native-app and Exponent. There is a nice list of open source examples here, some of then are mentioned to use Exponent.
https://github.com/ReactNativeNews/React-Native-Apps

I have few experience with nodejs. I already noticed there are several possible configurations for React Native apps. I usually use npm start to run it, but that don't work on those examples, since since they don't have a start script in package.json.

Take as an example the native-component-list app. How can I execute it after cloning and doing npm install?

Using node v6.11.4 and npm 3.10.10

I also tried using react-native run-android . It works when I create a new project with react-native init Ola2
But not with the downloaded code.

Here are some more details. I did this before: npm install -g react-native-cli

```
npm install

react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in xxx/native-component-list/node_modules (25ms)
Android project not found. Maybe run react-native android first?

react-native android
Scanning folders for symlinks in xxx/native-component-list/node_modules (26ms)
Unrecognized command 'android'
Run react-native --help to see list of all available commands
```

Comment: For any npm project, you have to make sure to run `npm install` before doing anything.

Comment: i did `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/getting-started.html#content), you can run the app with command `react-native run-android` (for android)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I just had never used Expo.io way to create a ReactNative app. I only knew the init and the crna ways. This apps where created with the exp tool. 
So,to run it, just do:

```
npm install exp --global
npm install
exp android    
exp start
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work on Expo, I prefer react-native-cli

In your case, your project in developed on Expo. 
So you need expo-cli to run the project.

For Expo Cli

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

For CRNA

```
npm i -g create-react-native-app
```

Internally CRNA use EXPO, so you can choose any option. After installing the **expo-cli**  `npm start` command work fine for you.

**Or you can eject this project.**

You can run `npm run eject` to get a project very similar to what **react-native init** would generate. At that point you’ll need Xcode and/or Android Studio just as you would if you started with react-native init , adding libraries with react-native link will work, and you’ll have full control over the native code compilation process.

Hope it will work for you.